# Table sorting is not working for dates in ie9, firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have date format Like this 
  2009-04-17 07:17:46.0

For this, sorting works in Chrome,but not working in Firefox, Ie9.

table sorter V 2.0.5

Comment: Was this ever solved? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [iso 8601 date parser](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-date-iso8601.js):

```
/*! ISO-8601 date parser
 * This parser will work with dates in ISO8601 format
 * 2013-02-18T18:18:44+00:00
 * Written by Sean Ellingham :https://github.com/seanellingham
 * See https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/247
 */
var iso8601date = /^([0-9]{4})(-([0-9]{2})(-([0-9]{2})(T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(:([0-9]{2})(\.([0-9]+))?)?(Z|(([-+])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})))?)?)?)?$/;
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id : 'iso8601date',
    is : function(s) {
        return s.match(iso8601date);
    },
    format : function(s) {
        var result = s.match(iso8601date);
        if (result) {
            var date = new Date(result[1], 0, 1);
            if (result[3]) { date.setMonth(result[3] - 1); }
            if (result[5]) { date.setDate(result[5]); }
            if (result[7]) { date.setHours(result[7]); }
            if (result[8]) { date.setMinutes(result[8]); }
            if (result[10]) { date.setSeconds(result[10]); }
            if (result[12]) { date.setMilliseconds(Number('0.' + result[12]) * 1000); }
            return date;
        }
        return s;
    },
    type : 'numeric'
});
```